# What does this urladdress statement mean?

Tags: url

The '?subject' and '&body' especially..

```
urlAddress = mailAddress+"?subject=" +mailSubject+"&body="+mailBody;
```

Comment: have a look at [query strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)

Comment: I don't see how this has anything to do with `android`, `eclipse`, and especially `nfc`...?

Comment: I am developing an android app to write info in an NFC App

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question mark denotes the start of parameters you are passing to the script. Subject is the first parameter. The '=' denotes an assignment, meaning subjects value is going to be whatever is in mailSubject. The ampersand denotes the start of a new parameter, in this case "body." Body's value will be whatever is in mailBody. You denote any number of new parameters to pass with more ampersands, for example:

```
someurl.com/somescript.php?parameter1=somevalue&parameter2=othervalue&parameter3=anothervalue
```